# Generating zip files in azure blob container --getting corrupted

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

Here I am trying to zip the contents of my azure blob directory using [dotnetzip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)

Here is the code I use to do this.
The zip files are getting created but are corrupted.
In my blob container 'myfiles' ,I want to create a zip file named "mymusic.zip" by reading all my files and folders within myMusic folder while retaining the same folder structure inside the zip file. The following code creates the zip file, but the zip file is getting corrupted .Any suggestions to resolve this ?

```
string ofurl = @"http://myxyzstorage.blob.core.windows.net/myfiles/mymusic";
            string ofBlob = @"http://myxyzstorage.blob.core.windows.net/myfiles";
          dBlob = new CloudBlob(blobClient.GetBlobReference(ofBlob));

            using (var zipFile = new ZipFile())
            {
                byte[] fileBytes = dBlob.DownloadByteArray();
                using (var fileStream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes))
                {
                    fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    zipFile.AddEntry("myZipFiles"+".zip", fileBytes);                    }
                var sas = ofContainer.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessPolicy()
                {
                    Permissions = SharedAccessPermissions.Write,
                 // SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(this.timeOutSeconds)
                });

                using (var zipStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    zipFile.Save(zipStream);
                    zipStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    var blobRef = ofContainer.GetBlobReference(ofurl);
                    blobRef.UploadFromStream(zipStream);
                }

            }
```

**here with my code above ,I can see the generated zip file myzipfile.zip inside my blob(http://myxyzstorage.blob.core.windows.net/myfiles/mymusic).But when I download and try to unzip ,its showing the error message "The compressed zipped folder "myzipfiles.zip" is invalid .Why my zip file are getting corrupted? how to prevent my zip file from getting corrupted**